# Createjs SVG not loading in IE11

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, createjs

I preload an SVG file using the Image abstract loader to get and img tag which i can then pass to createjs.Bitmap to get my image on stage.
This works great (bounds, etc.) for all browsers except IE11 which is the target browser.

```js
//var src = "https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--pEKSmwzm--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/1414228815325188681.jpg" //works
var src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Bitmap_VS_SVG.svg"


var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
queue.loadManifest({
  id: 'code',
  src: src,
  type: createjs.AbstractLoader.IMAGE
});



queue.on('complete', function () {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

stage.addChild(new createjs.Bitmap(queue.getResult('code')));
stage.update();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: perhaps related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494296/svg-not-showing-in-ie11

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608721/unable-to-preload-and-display-svg-with-createjs

Comment: There is also this one - i have had this before, when you have no width set : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26781221/svg-images-doesnt-appear-on-ie-11

Comment: It is strictly a createjs issue which has its own createjs canvas thus normal canvas does not apply.